# Want PopUp Message over each div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    function myFunc(n) {
        var v = document.createElement("span");
        var h = document.createTextNode("See This");
        v.id = "myPopup";
        v.className = "popuptext";
        v.appendChild(h);
        var p = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");

        p[n].appendChild(v);
        myFunction();
        //document.getElementById("myPopup").style.left ="0px";
    }
    function myFunction() {
        var v = document.getElementById('myPopup');
       v.classList.toggle('show');
    }
```

```css
        .popup {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

        .popup .popuptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 190px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 125%;
            left:0px;
            margin-left: -80px;

        }

            .popuptext::after {
                content: "";
                border-width: 5px;
                border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
                position: absolute;
                border-style: solid;
                top: 100%;
                left: 50%;
            }

       .show {
            visibility: visible !important;

        }
```

```html
  <h2>Hi</h2>

  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(0) ">
    Click Here1

  </div>&spades;&spades;
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(1) ">
    Click Here

  </div>&spades;&spades;
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(2) ">
    Click Here2
  </div>
```

I want when user click over div segment popup should come over same div. When user click on first div tag popup work correctly but when clicked over second div tag, popup appears but over first div tag. Same happens with third. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dynamically creating `myPopup` for every click. this will create elements with duplicate ids and when you fetch element, element that satisfies first will be used. Try adding `n` to the id of popup like `v.id = "myPopup_" + n;` and then pass it to `myFunction` and show it based on this `n`

```js
function myFunc(n) {
  var v = document.createElement("span");
  var h = document.createTextNode("See This");
  v.id = "myPopup_" + n;
  v.className = "popuptext";
  v.appendChild(h);
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");

  p[n].appendChild(v);
  myFunction(n);
  //document.getElementById("myPopup").style.left ="0px";
}

function myFunction(id) {
  var v = document.getElementById('myPopup_'+id);
  v.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 190px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hi</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(0) ">
  Click Here1

</div>&spades;&spades;
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(1) ">
  Click Here

</div>&spades;&spades;
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(2) ">
  Click Here2
</div>
```

Note: Ideally you should just add class and using querySelector you should search inside current div.

```js
function createNewPopup() {
  var v = document.createElement("span");
  var h = document.createTextNode("See This");
  v.className = "popuptext";
  v.appendChild(h);
  return v;
}

function myFunc(n) {
  var p = document.querySelectorAll(".popup")[n];
  if (!p.querySelector(".popuptext"))
    p.appendChild(createNewPopup());
  myFunction(p);
  //document.getElementById("myPopup").style.left ="0px";
}

function myFunction(el) {
  var v = el.querySelector(".popuptext")
  v.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 190px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hi</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(0) ">
  Click Here1

</div>&spades;&spades;
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(1) ">
  Click Here

</div>&spades;&spades;
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(2) ">
  Click Here2
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you  Sir.. This is what I wanted @Rajesh

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala Glad to help! Also I found an issue that you are appending new popups every time you click on div. You should check if it exists and if not then only add it. I have updated second snippet(querySelector one) to show same.

Comment: Thank You Sir. @Rajesh  I had not earlier noted this view. Lot useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the popup for it to reappear due to the fact that you use an id. JS only selects the first occurrence of an id. you should be safe when you use a class instead of an id. in the snippet I've made it to remove the active popup then show it again at the clicked element.

also a slight change in the arguments. you can just give the onclick in html the event. then use event.target to know which element was clicked by the user. this will eliminate the issue of counting the divs that you want clickable

```js
function myFunc(event) {
        var v = document.getElementById('myPopup');
        if(v){
          v.remove();
        }
        var v = document.createElement("span");
        var h = document.createTextNode("See This");
        v.id = "myPopup";
        v.className = "popuptext";
        v.appendChild(h);

        event.target.appendChild(v);
        myFunction();
        //document.getElementById("myPopup").style.left ="0px";
    }
    function myFunction() {
        var v = document.getElementById('myPopup');
        v.classList.toggle('show');
    }
```

```css
.popup {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

        .popup .popuptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 190px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 125%;
            left:0px;
            margin-left: -80px;

        }

            .popuptext::after {
                content: "";
                border-width: 5px;
                border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
                position: absolute;
                border-style: solid;
                top: 100%;
                left: 50%;
            }

       .show {
            visibility: visible !important;

        }
```

```html
<h2>Hi</h2>

  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(event) ">
    Click Here1

  </div>&spades;&spades;
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(event) ">
    Click Here

  </div>&spades;&spades;
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunc(event) ">
    Click Here2
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

var p = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");

when your are using this it always use the look for the first element with class "popup".

Hence your popup comes on first element.

Use 'id' attribute instead.

```
 function myFunc(n,id) {
        var v = document.createElement("span");
        var h = document.createTextNode("See This");
        v.id = "myPopup";
        v.className = "popuptext";
        v.appendChild(h);
        var p = document.getElementsById(id);

        p[n].appendChild(v);
        myFunction();
        //document.getElementById("myPopup").style.left ="0px";
    }
    function myFunction() {
        var v = document.getElementById('myPopup');
       v.classList.toggle('show');
    }
        .popup {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

        .popup .popuptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 190px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 125%;
            left:0px;
            margin-left: -80px;

        }

            .popuptext::after {
                content: "";
                border-width: 5px;
                border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
                position: absolute;
                border-style: solid;
                top: 100%;
                left: 50%;
            }

       .show {
            visibility: visible !important;

        }
  <h2>Hi</h2>

  <div class="popup" id="popup1" onclick="myFunc(0,'popup1') ">
    Click Here1

  </div>&spades;&spades;
  <div class="popup" id="popup2" onclick="myFunc(1,'popup2') ">
    Click Here

  </div>&spades;&spades;
  <div class="popup" id="popup3" onclick="myFunc(2,'popup3') ">
    Click Here2
  </div>
```